# Where to find Military Records in Latvian Army 1918-1920 Latvian War of Independence

Tags: military-records, latvia

Looking to find my Grandfathers military records.  He served in the Latvian Army during 1918-1920 in the Latvian War of Independence.  He was born in Walk and was in school in Dorpat(Tartu).  He left Tartu when Russians invaded.  He went to Riga to serve in Latvian Army in Dec 1918.